# node.js - broadcast message to all the connected

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

So we have the following node.js code -

```
var http = require('http');

var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World! \n");
  response.end(");
}).listen(8125);
```

Let's say I want to broadcast a message to all the connected users,
`write` method of `response` in the `createServer` function doesn't do that.

So how can I broadcast message to all the connected users/clients?

There is a way doing it with pure Node.js? because I'm just learning it now, and I prefer using pure node.js for now..

Comment: I would say [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Answer (score 3):

These are HTTP requests, therefore it isn't possible. HTTP requests start on first connection and end when all the data has been sent.

In your case, the data is

```
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World! \n");
```

And then connection is ended

```
response.end(");
```

If you're looking for something to keep live connections with, take a look at these:

[socket.io](https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/) - a realtime transport library that supports all platforms, and falls back for older software.
[WebSocket-Node](https://github.com/Worlize/WebSocket-Node) - a client and server websocket implementation.
[Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye) - publish-subscribe messaging system that uses the Bayeux protocol.

I have only used `socket.io` and this is how broadcasting is done.

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.broadcast.emit('user connected');
});
```

Comment: I hate stackoverflow! It all comes to the case who types faster :)

Comment: @NikitaLeonov Go practice that typing! ;)

Comment: There is a way doing it with pure Node.js? because I'm just learning it now, and I prefer using pure node.js for now...

Comment: You'd have to take a look at the source of the websocket emulation libraries. They're quite complicated, so I still suggest using `socket.io`. It's easy to install, and performance tuned.